# efficient combinations with condition

Tags: python, conditional-statements, combinations, python-itertools

Given the user input `n`, which represents the number of players, I calculate all the possible coalitions (tuples) of players and then all the possible sets of coalitions so that in each set each player belongs to one and only one coalition.
Example: `n = 3`

```
#coalitions
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]

#combinations of coalitions that respect the condition
[((1, 2, 3),), ((1,), (2, 3)), ((2,), (1, 3)), ((3,), (1, 2)), ((1,), (2,), (3,))]
```

In order to do this I wrote:

```
n = int(raw_input())
players = xrange(1,n+1)
players_comb = [coal for length in players for coal in list(combinations(players,length))]

coal_comb = [coalset for l in players for coalset in list(combinations(players_comb,l)) if sum(map(len,coalset)) == n and set(player for coal in coalset for player in coal) == set(players)]
```

Problem is that `coal_comb` is extremely inefficient. For istance it will compute all the combinations of length `n` even though only one (i.e.`((1 ... n),)`) respects the condition.

I think that the function is O(2^(2^n)).
My computer isn't even able to compute for n=6.

Any ideas on how to make it more efficient?

**UPDATE**
I came up with this solution:

```
combs = [comb for length in xrange(2,n) for comb in combinations_with_replacement(players,length) if sum(comb) == n]
H = [tuple(players_comb[:n]),(players_comb[-1],)]
for comb in combs:
    layouts = set(frozenset(layout) for layout in product(*[[coal for coal in players_comb if len(coal) == length] for length in comb]) if set(player for coal in layout for player in coal) == set(players))
    H.extend(tuple(tuple(layout) for layout in layouts))
```

But it is just a marginal improvement: now I can compute for `n = 8` (more than 50 seconds running time).

Comment: Have a look at the pythons [itertools.combination](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: @cybermoon ehm, what about it? I'm already using itertools.combinations ...